# Updating a a json in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

The `text` does not not update. Here is our code.

```
<some-builder :blaa="{name: 'something', type: 1}"></some-builder>
```

On the `some-builder.vue`

```
<input type="text" v-model="blaa.type" />
<button type="button"  @click="selectType('1')">1</button>
<button type="button"  @click="selectType('2')">2</button>
<button type="button"  @click="selectType('3')">3</button>


export default {
  props: ["blaa"],
  components: {},
  methods: {
    selectType(t) {
      this.blaa.type = t;
      console.log(this.blaa);
    },
  },
};
```

As you can see we have a click event that would change the `type` of `blaa` json. The `console.log` works just fine but the text box that has model `blaa.type` does not change.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

mutating the prop inside the child component is not a good approach therefore, you can do a emit instead

**Parent.vue**

```
<some-builder :blaa="blaa" @update-blaa="updateBlaa"></some-builder>

export default {
 data() {
  return {
   blaa: {name: 'something', type: 1},
  };
 },
 methods: {
  updateBla(val) {
   this.blaa.type = val;
  },
 }
}
```

and then use **:value** instead of **v-model** in some-builder component as shown in below

```
<input type="text" :value="blaa.type" @input="$emit('update-blaa', $event.target.value)" />
<button type="button"  @click="selectType('1')">1</button>
<button type="button"  @click="selectType('2')">2</button>
<button type="button"  @click="selectType('3')">3</button>


export default {
  props: ["blaa"],
  components: {},
  methods: {
    selectType(type) {
      this.$emit('update-blaa', type);
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Vue (no matter Vue2 or Vue3) is [One-Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow), you can't change the parent data in children directly.

---

in **Vue2**

```
// parent component

<child-component
    :blaa="blaa"
    @update-blaa="updateBlaa"/>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
           blaa: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateBlaa(newValue) {
            this.blaa = newValue;
        }
    }
}

// child component

<input type="text" v-model="computedBlaa.type" />
<button type="button"  @click="selectType('1')">1</button>
<button type="button"  @click="selectType('2')">2</button>
<button type="button"  @click="selectType('3')">3</button>

export default {
    props: [
       'blaa'
    ],
    computed: {
        computedBlaa: {
            get() {
                return this.blaa;
            },
            set(value) {
                this.$emit('update-blaa', value);
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        selectType(t) {
           this.computedBlaa.type = t;
        }
    }
}
```

---

in **Vue3**

Since Vue3 support [multiple v-model bindings](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html), you can do it with more elegant code.

```html
// parent component

<child-component
    v-model:blaa="blaa"/>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const blaa = ref({
    name: 'something',
    type: 1
});
<script>

// child component

<input type="text" v-model="computedBlaa.type" />
<button type="button"  @click="computedBlaa.type = 1">1</button>
<button type="button"  @click="computedBlaa.type = 2">2</button>
<button type="button"  @click="computedBlaa.type = 3">3</button>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps(['blaa']);
const emits = defineEmits(['update:blaa']);

const computedBlaa = computed({
    get() {
       return props.blaa;
    },
    set(value) {
        emits('update:blaa', value);
    }
});
</script>
```